# ReportViewerSession Expired

Tags: asp.net, session, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am using telerik Tabstrip.In the page views(4) I have Reportviewers.

The reports are in third and fourth tabs.By the time I get to the tab after a while the Report viewer session gets expired.

I tried KeepSessionAlive=true,but didn't help.Can some one suggest the fix for this?

```
         <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"  KeepSessionAlive="true"
                Height="1400px" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" SizeToReportContent="True"
                Visible="true">
           <ServerReport ReportPath="/Prod/EmployeeReport" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>    

                </telerik:RadPageView>
```

**Error:**

```
      Exception information: Exception type: AspNetSessionExpiredException Exception       message: Die ASP.NET-Sitzung ist abgelaufen oder konnte nicht gefunden >werden. at 
 Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ViewerDataOperation..ctor() at        
  Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType) at          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at  System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionS>   tep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&                           >completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem like you for 3 days, and i had tried almost everything like initializing session variable, increase sessionState timeout, set cookieless=false, configuring a sessionstate server, but nothing worked for me.

I figured out that setting requireSSL from true to false solved the issue because i was not accesing the page using SSL

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="" />
```

Here is my reportviewer config in my aspx page

```
<rsweb: ReportViewer ID ="ReportViewer1" runat ="server" Font-Names ="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
 SizeToReportContent="true" InteractivityPostBackMode="AlwaysSynchronous" AsyncRendering="true" KeepSessionAlive="true"
     ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="865px">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/REPORTFOLDER/REPORTNAME"   ReportServerUrl="http://localhost/Reportserver" />
```